# C# LINQ: Get count for each row

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Here the query for retrieving all the *comptes* in my base.

I would like to add a number within the object GridCompte in order to count the element inside the list (1,2,3...):

```
var comptes = (from c in Comptes                           
               join s in Societies on c.IdSoc equals s.IdSoc    
               select new GridCompte
               {
                   SocCompteId = c.IdCompte,                               
                   Name = c.Name,
                   Nb = ??? COUNT ???,
                   .....
                   SocName = s.Name
               }).ToList();
```

I tried using the **group** statement, but i didn't manage to achieve my goal.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you elaborate? What is the list you want to count? Where is it coming from the Societies or Comptes tables?

Comment: I've already tried using a second query, but the issue is that I have 10k of data and the performances are not optimized if I make a second query.

Answer (score 0):

First prepare your linq only for the fields you want to get

```
var comptes = from c in Comptes                           
                   join s in Societies on c.IdSoc equals s.IdSoc    
                   select new 
                   {
                       SocCompteId = c.IdCompte,                               
                       Name = c.Name,                        

                       .....
                       SocName = s.Name
                   };
```

Now use index option that is available in Select

```
var finalComptes =  (comptes.AsEnumerable()
                .Select((comptes, index) => new GridCompte()
                        {
                            SocCompteId = c.IdCompte,                               
                            Name = c.Name,
                            Nb = index + 1,

                            .....
                            SocName = s.Name                               
                        }).ToList();
```

Comment: I've already used this solution (multi-query), the issue is that I have 10k of data and the performances are not optimized if I make a second query.